# Is it possible to remove shortcut labels in Launcher Pro?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, home-screen-shortcuts, launcherpro

Is there a fast or automatic way to remove the labels from all home shortcuts, while using Launcher Pro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.   On the home screen, hit the Option button, then go to Preferences > Appearance Settings > Hide icon labels and check the box.